# GooglePlayServices[GoogleMap API] - Can't see a map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

For some reason i can't see any map using the google play services `API`.

activity_map:

```
package com.m.get.dl;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(Map.this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) 
    {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); // Setting map type
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

I think the problem lies in the XML file - activity_map.xml:

```
<fragment 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.m.get.dl"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="My key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So in the activity i get this screen instead of a map.

[image]

So is my `fragment` tag is wrong?

Comment: Try SupportMapFragment because your FragmentActivity is from support library.        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: It giving NullPointerException. But all the idea is that i don't want to use `SupportMapFragment`, i want to use `MapFragment`.

Comment: @sembozdemir And i changed all my code to use `SupportMapFragment` and the result is the same. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Did you got the right `api key`? Make sure your check that in your Manifest. Under `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="My key" />` Also you can refer to the official repo here:https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/BasicMapDemoActivity.java and the xml is here: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/res/layout/basic_demo.xml

Comment: @bjiang The `API Key` is that a copy paste from the `Google Developers Console` so i don't know what might be wrong with that. And the links basically did what i did in here. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Check the server key you are using. Make sure you have used accurate SHA-1 and package name. Rest of the code looks good!

Also, check the log if you are getting any error like:

```
Authentication failed on the server...
```

This says your key is not correct.

**Updated:**

You will be getting this log after the 'Authentication failed...'

```
Ensure that the following Android Key exists: ...
```

You can get correct SHA-1 key and package name below this 'Ensure that...' error message.
Both are separated by ';'

And now create new API key and add this new key in Manifest file  tag.

```
**Manifest:**
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

This will solve your problem!

Comment: Actually i got this `Authentication failed on the server...` on the Log. How do i get to that "google_maps_api.xml" file?

Comment: And what the server key? you mean ApI key?

Comment: If you have used New->Google->Google map Activity, then "google_maps_api.xml" file and manifest entry field are automatically generated. You can find this file here:

Android Studio 'Project' view -> app -> src -> release -> res -> values -> google_maps_api.xml

Same file can give you accurate SHA-1 key and your package name. Both fields are ';' separated. You can find detailed instructions in this file to create the server key.

Comment: I use `Eclipse` and i don't have any option for new->googleMapActivity. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ooh..I will check similar options for Eclipse and let you know..!!

Comment: There is no similar file in Eclipse. I have updated the answer to help you. Please go through the Updated part of answer. This will help you!

Comment: But i already did that. I have the correct `SHA-1` and i got the key from Google console and i have the `<meta data/>` tage with the key in my manifest...

Comment: If you are still getting 'Authentication failed..' error, it means your SHA-1 fingerprint and/or package name is incorrect. Try creating a new key and make sure you do not get 'Authentication failed..' error.

Also I think following options can help you:-
1. Recreating key
2. Clear the application data
3. uninstall the app and re-run